# Am I a sailor or a bunny?

Tags: riddle

> When I am blue, you can drink me
>   When I am red, I'll disappear
>
> I have serenity and cleverness
>   But I become a wolf if you double me
>
> I have only 12 friends
>   But I haven't seen them in a while

Who am I?

Comment: this is so genius confusingly riddle.. nice!

Comment: Is this somewhat related to the moon? This is indeed a confusing one ^^ I like it

Comment: [combination of bunny and a sailor :D](http://th04.deviantart.net/fs4/200H/i/2004/226/4/7/Sailor_Moon_Bunnies.jpg)..

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Are you:

> The moon

Am I a sailor or a bunny?

> Sailor moon: a Japanese anime
>  [Moon rabbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_rabbit): image of rabbit that appears on the surface of moon

When I am blue, you can drink me

> Blue moon beer or blue moon cocktail, also moonshine

When I am red, I'll disappear

> During a lunar eclipse, the moon turns red

I have serenity and cleverness

> Mare Serenetatis, Mare Ingenii (sea of serenity, sea of cleverness) are two named plains on the moon

But I become a wolf if you double me

> Werewolves appear during a full moon

I have only 12 friends

> Twelve months: the word moon is related to the word month

But I haven't seen them in a while

> Once in a blue moon

Comment: You got it but some clues are not correct. The last 3 clues are not correct.

Comment: Maybe 12 constellations of the zodiac

Comment: @AJL nope. That's not it

Comment: Moon Moon is the name of a meme wolf. http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/moon-moon

Comment: Incidentally, for the title clue: Sailor Moon is often the subject of "rabbit" jokes or puns, as her name (Usagi) translates literally to rabbit. Not sure if that was intentional or just happened to work. (She actually appears to be named for the very same "moon rabbit" legend, so either one is really correct.)

Answer (score 8):

I'm thinking the wolf line might refer to

> [Moon Moon](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/moon-moon) of memetic fame

Comment: you're right :)

Answer (score 7):

For the last two lines:

> The 12 men who've walked on the moon. Neither they nor anyone else have been back there in quite some time.

Comment: Yeap that's it. Congrats!

Answer (score 4):

Here's my attempt at explanations for the last 3 lines.

*But I become a wolf if you double me*

> [Two Moons](http://wot.wikia.com/wiki/Two_Moons) is a wolf in the brilliant Wheel of Time series of novels.

(I don't know if this is what the OP meant, but it fits perfectly!)

*I have only 12 friends

 But I haven't seen them in a while*

Possibility 1:

> [Twelve Moons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Moons).

Possibility 2:

> there are thirteen moon cycles in a year, so each one has 12 friends, but they're spaced out through the year and don't see much of each other.

Possibility 3:

> there are twelve other moons in the Solar System (around Jupiter, Saturn, etc.) bigger than a certain size.

Comment: I like your answers they are matching but it is not what I meant. In that case, I don't know if I should award the answer or not. Any insight?

Comment: @A.D. Depends what you mean by "award". By all means upvote it if you like it, but I think JS1 should get the tick since he got the answer first (if not a perfect explanation for every line).

Comment: I was talking about the tick indeed. Thank you

Comment: @A.D. But if you want people to get the intended explanations for the last 3 lines, maybe wait to award the tick? People tend to be more interested in looking at questions without an accepted answer.

Comment: I noticed that. I was waiting for it. If there is no further answer tomorrow, I'll add the explanation for the last 3 lines.